# If I don't fill all the first email (of 3) the action doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, email

I have this script to send automatically the load information by email:

```
if(confirm('', 'Are you sure?') == true) {

// enviar mails
var emails = new Array();
if (getFormFieldValue('4469') != '') {
    emails[0] = getFormFieldValue('4469');
}
if (getFormFieldValue('4470') != '') {
    emails[1] = getFormFieldValue('4470');
}
if (getFormFieldValue('4471') != '') {
    emails[2] = getFormFieldValue('4471');
}

var msgBody =   'blablabla' ; 

var s = new SendMessage();

if(emails.length > 0) {
s.sendEmailMessage(emails, msgBody);
}


confirmForm();
}
```

As you can see, there are 3 mails, if I don't fill the first one, nothing happen, if i complete only the second or the thirst email also nothing. The only way to executed this script is filling the first email.

How can i fix this?

Thank you

Comment: [tag:java] is ***not*** [tag:javascript].

Answer (score 2):

Try using an array index variable to keep track of which entry in the email array you are populating.  You want to always start with index 0, then 1, etc. regardless of which emails are filled in:

```
var emails == new Array();
var emailIndex = 0;
if (getFormFieldValue('4469') != '') {
    emails[emailIndex ++] = getFormFieldValue('4469');
}
if (getFormFieldValue('4470') != '') {
    emails[emailIndex ++] = getFormFieldValue('4470');
}
if (getFormFieldValue('4471') != '') {
    emails[emailIndex ++] = getFormFieldValue('4471');
}
// emails should be populated now starting from index 0
```

If the form field values are always incremental from 4469-4471, you can also simplify and shorten your code with a `for` loop:

```
var emails = new Array();
var emailIndex = 0;
for (var fld = 4469; fld <= 4471; fld++)
    if (getFormFieldValue(fld.toString()) != '')
        emails[emailsIndex++] = getFormFieldValue(fld.toString());
```

**EDIT**: As noted by @Naren, this can be made even simpler by using [**`Array.push`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
var emails = new Array();
for (var fld = 4469; fld <= 4471; fld++)
    if (getFormFieldValue(fld.toString()) != '')
        emails.push(getFormFieldValue(fld.toString()));
```

Comment: we can also use emails.push method rather calculating the index.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Array.push(), like this:

```
var x = getFormFieldValue(y);
if (x != '') emails.push(x);
```

This can be easily used iteratively: you can for example create an array with the field values to read from and loop over it.